# Consuming Analytics from Parse.com in an IOS App

Tags: ios7, parse-platform, analytics

I am generating custom Parse Analytic events in the background cloud code based on Save events from my ios app . I can also see it in the Analytic panel on Parse.com. 
How do I access it in my ios app ? 
I get the following error when I try

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0x7a9697e0 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7a956d00> { URL: https://api.parse.com/1/events/commentsAnalytics } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "*";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 36;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Fri, 23 Jan 2015 06:43:38 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.6.0";
    "X-Parse-Platform" = G1;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.007086";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/1/events/commentsAnalytics, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400),
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are adding the **keys** *(X-Parse-Application-Id and X-Parse-REST-API-Key)* of your application in the **request header**. Here is an example with Alamofire.

### Example

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.parse.com/1/events/Buy")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("<APPLICATION-KEY>", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
request.setValue("<REST-KEY>", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")

var parameter: NSDictionary = ["dimensions" :["product" : ["name" : "macpro", "price" : "350"]]]
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameter, options: nil, error: nil)

Alamofire.request(request).response { (request, response, result, error) -> Void in
// handle response
       println("\(request) \t \(response) \t \(result) \t \(error) ")
}
```

### Checking

to check the event, go to your application panel in the parse ...

[image: Check Events @ Analytics Tab]

...click "Custom Breakdown"...

[image]

and customize your chart.